# Map dictionary [String:Any] to class

Tags: json, swift

I was wondering if there is a way to map a dictionary to a class. If this is my class:

```
class Class{
    var x = 0
    var y = "hi"
}
```

And this is my dictionary (`dict`) with type `[String: Any]`

```
["x": 1, "y": "hello"]
```

Is there any easy way to convert the values of the dictionary to my class `Class`?

I now do it like this:

```
classInstance.x = dict["x"] as? Int ?? 0
```

I would like to know if it possible to search in the JSON for a key that matches the name of the variable of the class and if it matches, assign the value of the JSON's key to the value of the variable of the class. In my way (above) I need to type it line by line and maybe there is a one-liner to map the JSON into the class.

Comment: Don't know if you want to avoid any third party libs for this but I could recommend https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper

Comment: Why `[String: Any]`. The dictionary is `[String:Int]`. Using this specific type you could easily decode the dictionary to struct or class with `Codable`.

Comment: Why not use `Codable` to parse JSON?

Comment: @Miknash For this simple case `Codable` is more convenient and powerful than any third party library.

Comment: @vadian I haven't explicit mentioned that  the values could be anything, so not only Int. It should support String as well for example.

Comment: no problem with that - as far as I can understand, this was just an example - It is arguable that json will always contain only Ints

Comment: @J.Doe Then please ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Built-in solution with `JSONSerialization` and `Codable`

```
let dictionary : [String:Any] = ["x": 1, "y": "hello"]

class Class : Codable {
    let x : Int
    let y : String
}

do {
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary)
    let instance = try JSONDecoder().decode(Class.self, from: jsonData)
    print(instance.x, instance.y)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Works exactly liked I hoped :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Decodable` instead of `Codable`?

Answer (score 0):

This is how my function finally looks. It takes in any object that conforms to Decodable and return a subclass from the JSONData :)

```
import UIKit

class DecodeObject{

    func decode<T: Decodable>(data: [String : Any], type: T.Type) -> T? {
        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data)
            return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: jsonData)
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You should make the method also `throw` and hand over the error. `func decode<T: Decodable>(data: [String : Any], type: T.Type) throws -> T` and remove the `do - catch` block

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == Any {
    func decode<T: Decodable>() throws -> T? {
        do {
            let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self)
            return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            throw error
        }
    }
}

struct Person: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}

let person: Person? = try? ["name": "fred", "age": 12].decode()
```